# Printing user arugments in while loop

Tags: perl, while-loop, arguments

I'm trying to take user arguments into an array and print them into a while loop, can anyone help?

```
my @user_args = sort (@ARGV);
chomp(@user_args);
my $i = -1;
while (++$i <= $#ARGV)
{

    print "$ARGV[$i] \n";

}



print "\nStep #2\n";
my @user_args2 = sort {$b cmp $a} @ARGV;
while (++$i <= $#ARGV)
{

    print "@user_args2[$i] \n";

}
```

this is my updated code, I'm trying now to figure out how to sort it increasingly and decreasing based off of these arguments "Ask ask as How 100 "abc def" oK ok" please help!

Comment: Yes. Change `while` to `foreach`, and then brush up on [`perlsyn`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlsyn).

Comment: it's for an assignment I have to do it in a while loop.

Comment: please explain more about how you want to sort your array?Please give an input and an expected output.

Comment: **Always** add [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html "perldoc strict") and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html "perldoc warnings") to the beginning of **every** Perl program, until you know **exactly** why it is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

`while` repeats the loop as long as the condition expression is true.

If the user supplied some args, `@user_args` will be true, so the loop will be entered. Since the loop doesn't change `@user_args`, the loop will repeat indefinitely.

If you want to use `while`, you'll have to change your condition to something that isn't constant. For example, you could change `@user_args` in the loop body. What if you were to remove the first element of `@user_args` each pass of the loop...

Answer (score 0):

Like @ikegami said, your loop is an endless loop.  If a user passes in the arguments "abc" and "123", the contents of `@user_args` will be `('abc', 123)` each iteration of the while loop.

There are many ways to make this happen, but one way would be to use `shift` to take the first item out of the `@user_args` array.  Do this inside the while loop, that way, once you shift off the last element from the array, the while loop will no longer value as true, and the while loop will exit.

See the [shift documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) for more information how to shift elements out of an array.

Comment: Right - sorry.  That wording is a little confusing - I am editing to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it do it in while loop, then use another variable $i, for keeping the index being printed of the array, like this:

```
#!usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $i = -1;
while ( ++$i <= $#ARGV ) 
{

    print "$ARGV[$i]\n";

}
```

$#ARGV gives the index of the last element of array $#ARGV, e.g. if @ARGV is like this:

```
@ARGV = ("one","two");
```

then $#ARGV will give 1, which is the index of the second element, "two".

Comment: @simbabque I've edited my answer, now it may be easy for the OP to explain this code